# MotionLayout and constraint Groups

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I am going to start using `MotionLayout`.
After replacing existing `ConstraintLayout` with the MotionLayout, 
which has a simple motion scene,
I noticed that `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group` is not working anymore.
Initially, I showed one of the two groups depending on a condition,
but now both of them are visible, even though I set visibility to `GONE`.
Could I somehow get MotionLayout to work with Groups, or I should use different MotionLayouts?

Comment: Show your xml file. (scene, layout)

Comment: @DmitroIvanov Seems it doesn't matter what layout is it. Just create a group within a MotionLayout  and try to change the group's visibility

Comment: @LeoDroidcoder i also face same issue now. any solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most recent version of ConstraintLayout is 2.0.0-beta2 and verified that MotionScene does not care about `androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.Group`. So if you want to change visibility or elevation value you should handle it individually for each View instead of applying to the virtual Group.

Answer (score 0):

The latest stable version of MotionLayout (2.0.4) allows you to change visibility via Groups. Unfortunately it requires setting `visibilityMode="ignore"` on the Group and all its referenced views. Here's a working example:

#### Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
        android:id="@+id/test_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="text_view"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

#### MotionScene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:lol="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        lol:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        lol:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        />

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/text_view">
            <PropertySet lol:visibilityMode="ignore" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/test_group">
            <PropertySet lol:visibilityMode="ignore" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/text_view">
            <PropertySet lol:visibilityMode="ignore" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint android:id="@+id/test_group">
            <PropertySet lol:visibilityMode="ignore" />
        </Constraint>
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

#### MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button = findViewById<View>(R.id.button)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val group = findViewById<Group>(R.id.test_group)
            group.isVisible = !group.isVisible
        }
    }
}
```